# Running multiple instances of a Batch file in windows simultaneously?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a windows batch file that is invoked by windows scheduler. When I try to have multiple windows scheduler tasks trying to run the batch file simultaneously, the batch file is locked by the first process and the all the other instances fail.

Is there is way in Windows to run multiple instances of batch file simultaneously?

My script is a simple one all it does is:

```
set java_classpath
java javaClass
```

Comment: If you run simultaneously multiple instances of your batch file outside of the task scheduler, do they run?

Comment: No windows locks the file for the current process that is running the file.

Comment: Can it be that the batch file has some redirect to another file and that this file is what gets locked? Windows does not lock batch files, i have written some batch files that modifies themselves while running.

Comment: What happens to those java processes? Are they visible in task manager? Do they terminate? Can you start them several in parallel from command line, e.g. `start java javaClass` `start java javaClass` `start java javaClass`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing inherent to batch file mechanics that limits the number of processes that can simultaneously run the same script. The actual batch script is not locked when it is run. In fact, it is possible to modify a batch script while it is running, though that is usually a very bad idea.

But a batch script could take any number of actions that would prevent simultaneous runs. The most obvious is if the script attempts to redirect output to a specific file (constant path and name). The output redirection establishes an exclusive lock that will prevent any other process from obtaining the same lock.

Another possibility is your script could be calling an external command or program that establishes an exclusive lock in some way.

Either way, there should be nothing to prevent multiple processes from launching the same script simultaneously. But if the script establishes an exclusive lock, then one (or more) of the instances may either crash or exit prematurely, or seem to hang, depending on how the failed lock aquisition is handled.

There really isn't any way to be more specific unless you post your actual script. But if it is a long script, then you should attempt to isolate where the problem is occurring before posting.

Comment: Added my batch script in the question. My batch is a simple one all it does is run set the java class path and run a java class

Comment: There is certainly nothing in the batch script itself that would cause a problem, but java is an example of an external program that can establish exclusive locks. There must be something in your java class that is preventing parallel runs. This is not a batch-file issue.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8  task scheduler has the following option (on the last, "Settings" tab):
**If the task is already running, then the following rule applies:**

- Do not start a new instance (default)
- Run a new instance in parallel
- ...

Probably you should change this setting. And also, I would suggest you look into http://serverfault.com and post there.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try calling your batchfile by using `%systemroot%\cmd.exe /K C:\path\batchfile.bat`? With /K each time a new instance of cmd is opened, guess it is the shell not the file making you weird.

Answer (score 0):

to people coming here from google simply looking for a way to run multiple instances of a .bat file simultaneously, a simple way would be this script:

```
set N=3
for /L %%i in (1,1,%N%) do (
  start yourscript.bat
)
```